# Background tab not active in IE

Tags: asp.net, ajax, session

I have a web application that has an AJAX script running in the background to keep the session alive.

AJAX request goes to server and server replies current datetime back to the client. That datetime is displayed in the status bar.

It is all good when the browser has only 1 tab open or the app is the active tab.
However, if that application becomes background tab (some other tab is active/focused) it would not keep the session alive.

I have downloaded Fiddler and looked at the HTTP requests and I can see the requests going and being replied with correct datetime.

One thing I've noticed: When I keep the tab in the background, wait few minutes and come back, the status bar displays old datetime (datetime of when I put the tab in the background) until it ticks over the scheduled time. However, when I check Fiddler, requests/responses have been working all along.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on? Shouldn't client sending a request sufficient to keep the session alive, even when the app tab is in the background?

Comment: What do you mean by **Tab in the Background**?

Comment: Its possible that your page was cached and why not use javascript to keep the session alive?

Comment: Background Tab: When you have multiple tabs open, the one you are browsing right this instance is the active tab and all other tabs are background tabs.

Comment: I am using javascript to keep the session alive.